# use of e.g before a \citeasnoun

Tags: citing, harvard-style

I'm trying to add an e.g before using a `\citeasnoun` but does not work.

If I used like this `\citeasnoun[e.g.][]{Hernandez2009}` it appears in the pdf as  Hernandez et al. (e.g. 2009).

Nevertheless, if I used only with `\cite` it works perfectly. For example, `\cite[e.g.][]{Hernandez2009}` = `\cite[e.g.][]{Hernandez2009}`

What should I do?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It looks like you're using the `harvard` citation management package along with one one of the seven bibliography styles provided by that package -- `agsm`, `apsr`, `dcu`, `jmr`, `jphysicsB`, `kluwer`, `dcu`, or `nederlands`. Is this correct? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using the `harvard` citation management package and some of its macros to generate citation callout. (Just for readers of this posting who may be more familiar with the `natbib` citation management package: The `natbib`-equivalents of the `harvard` macros `\cite` and `\citeasnoun` are `\citep` and `\citet`, respectively.)

In my view, no good purpose is served by trying to make the first optional argument of `\citeasnoun` non-empty. (The same holds for `\citet` as well, by the way.) If you really need to prefix something to a text-style citation callout, just write

```
... e.g., \citeasnoun{herandez2009}, ...
```

i.e., place the string "e.g.," *before* and outside `\citeasnoun`.

An MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{hernandez2009,
  author = "Ana Hernandez and A. BCD and E. FGH",
  title  = "Deep Thoughts",
  year   = "2009",
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib,har2nat} % 'har2nat' translates harvard macros to natbib speak
\bibliographystyle{agsm} % just a guess...
\begin{document}
good:

\cite[e.g.,][p.~29]{hernandez2009}

\citep[e.g.,][p.~29]{hernandez2009}

\bigskip
bad:

\dots, \citeasnoun[e.g.,][p.~29]{hernandez2009}, \dots

\dots, \citet[e.g.,][p.~29]{hernandez2009}, \dots

\bigskip
do this instead:

\dots, e.g., \citeasnoun[p.~29]{hernandez2009}, \dots

\dots, e.g., \citet[p.~29]{hernandez2009}, \dots

\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```